# Display multiple rows as an array

Tags: php, mysql

I want to be able to display a table with a list of people in one column and a string of their orders in another.

```
People
========
person_id
fname
lname

Orders
========
order_id
person_id
product_id

Products
=========
product_id
productname
```

I have the following code:

```
SELECT people.fname, people.lname, products.productname
FROM people
INNER JOIN orders ON people.person_id = orders.person_id
INNER JOIN products ON products.product_id = orders.product_id
ORDER BY lname
...
$rows = $result->num_rows;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>Edit</td>
    <td>".$row["lname"].", ".$row['fname']."</td>
    <td>".$row['productname']."</td></tr>";
    }
```

This displays:
    Smith, Bob | Item 1 
    Smith, Bob | Item 2 
    Smith, Bob | Item 3 
    Roberts, Jill | Item 2
    etc..
What I want is for it to display:
    Smith, Bob | Item 1, Item 2, Item 3
    Roberts, Jill | Item 2
How do I show the name (based on person_id) only once and then a list of their orders in another column?

Comment: You're probably looking for `GROUP_CONCAT` on `productname` in your query.

Comment: also add your MySql Query

Comment: I added the SQL.  Could you explain the GROUP_CONCAT a little more?  I've having trouble finding out how to use it in this situation.  (Thank you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you have to use the `GROUP_CONCAT` function. For example something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(LNAME,", ",FNAME), GROUP_CONCAT(PRODUCTNAME)
FROM PEOPLE P, PRODUCTS PR, ORDERS O
WHERE P.PERSON_ID = O.PERSON_ID
AND O.PRODUCT_ID = PR.PRODUCT_ID
GROUP BY (LNAME, FNAME);
```

Comment: I have tried it, but I'm getting a Parse error.  It's rejecting the " ," between lname and fname

Comment: I have run this on Mysql it is not giving me an error. Can you tell me wat exact error you are getting.

Comment: Ok, I was able to fix the parse error.  GROUP_CONCAT is now listing one single row with every product on it.  It's not using the loop.  In my example, it's giving me: Smith, Bob | Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, Item 2.  It's not giving me a row for Jill, and it put her Item 2 attached to Bob's.

Comment: With so maneuvering, I was able to get this solution to work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Php oriented solution :

You could store your product names in an array, using the person's name as a key :

```
$rows = $result->num_rows;

$data = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
     $name = $row["lname"].", ".$row['fname'];
     $data[$name][] = $row['productname'];
}
```

Then, you'll just have to loop through this array :

```
foreach($data as $name => $products)
{
     echo "<tr><td>Edit</td><td>".$name."</td>";
     foreach($products as $productname)
     {
         echo "<td>".$productname."</td>";
     }
     echo "<tr>";
}
```